# Limit file upload size across multiple files

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I'm using jQuery file upload https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

I would like to set a maximum file size that applies to the file size of all attachments combined. In other words if the max limit is 10mb then the user can upload as many files as they wish, but the combined size of them all cannot exceed 10mb.

I see in the documentation I can set this constraint on a single file, but not all of them combined. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I accomplished it by reviewing how the jquery.fileupload-validation.js file works and this is what I came up with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (factory) {
        'use strict';
        if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
            // Register as an anonymous AMD module:
            define([
                'jquery',
                './jquery.fileupload-process'
            ], factory);
        } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
            // Node/CommonJS:
            factory(require('jquery'));
        } else {
            // Browser globals:
            factory(
                window.jQuery
            );
        }
    }(function ($) {
        'use strict';

        // Append to the default processQueue:
        $.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.options.processQueue.push(
            {
                action: 'validateTotalSize',
                // Always trigger this action,
                // even if the previous action was rejected: 
                always: true,
                // Options taken from the global options map:
                maxSizeOfFiles: '@',
            }
        );

        $.widget('blueimp.fileupload', $.blueimp.fileupload, {

            options: {
                /*
                // The maximum allowed size of all files combined in bytes:
                maxSizeOfFiles: 10000000, // 10 MB
                */

                // Function returning the current size of files,
                // has to be overriden for maxSizeOfFiles validation:
                getSizeOfFiles: $.noop,

                // Error and info messages:
                messages: {
                    maxSizeOfFiles: 'Maximum size of all files exceeded',
                }
            },

            processActions: {

                validateTotalSize: function (data, options) {
                    var $this = $(this),
                        that = $this.data('blueimp-fileupload') ||
                            $this.data('fileupload');

                    if (options.disabled) {
                        return data;
                    }

                    var dfd = $.Deferred(),
                        settings = this.options,
                        file = data.files[data.index];

                    console.log(settings.getSizeOfFiles());
                    if (settings.getSizeOfFiles() > options.maxSizeOfFiles) {
                        file.error = settings.i18n('maxSizeOfFiles');
                    }
                    //else {
                    //    delete file.error;
                    //}

                    if (file.error || data.files.error) {
                        data.files.error = true;
                        dfd.rejectWith(this, [data]);
                    } else {
                        dfd.resolveWith(this, [data]);
                    }

                    return dfd.promise();
                }
            }
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var totalSize = 0;

            $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                autoUpload: false,
                acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
                dataType: 'json',
                maxFileSize: 2000000, // 2 MB
                maxSizeOfFiles: 10000000, // 10 MB
                getSizeOfFiles: function () {
                    return totalSize;
                },
            });

            $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                    console.log('Adding file: ' + file.name + ', ' + file.size);
                    totalSize = totalSize + file.size;
                    console.log('Total size: ' + totalSize);
                });
            });

            $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadfailed', function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                    console.log('Removed file: ' + file.name + ', ' + file.size);
                    totalSize = totalSize - file.size;
                    console.log('Total size: ' + totalSize);
                });
            });
        });
    }));
</script>
```